# Display ALT-219 █ in TextView on Android - Extended ASCII

Tags: android, textview

I want to display a block character "ALT-219" in a TextView.  It isn't easy to search Google or stackoverflow for this as block means so many other things but I tried. I experimented with saving the file as a UTF-8 and my entire project crashed in some unexplainable way, I went to backups, that crashed in even worse ways.  I finally backed out of what I did and rebuilt so I am back to scratch but I am not inclined to experiment without asking for help.

What I am really trying to do is create a pseudo graphic meter so that I have different strings for different values like a gas gauge where there are different number of ALT-219 characters as the values change. This gives me a gauge 1/4 inch high on the screen that goes from one edge to the other and when the tank is empty, no ALT-219 and when full the entire line is full. Not really a gas gauge but I am just trying to explain it.

Comment: seems to me like you should be using [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) instead of trying to create an ascii version of one. for one thing not all devices having the same screen size so on a smaller device your gauge is probably going to get split into two lines which will look weird.

Comment: Maybe he is trying to make a retro DOS app. Just kidding... Allen Edwards, any reason why you don't want a ProgressBar?

Comment: I guess I should have picked a better analogy.  My data is positive and negative with a "|" character when the reading is right on zero.  The total display is +-1 in .1 increments so only 21 characters wide.  I actually got it to work before it crashed after a small mod and it looked exactly like what I wanted where the progress bar is not.

Comment: The character you refer to is called ["Full Block"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm) and its Unicode code is `\u2588`. You may try to use that code to display the character, but I second what @Tim suggested you in the comment above - consider to use ProgressBar instead.

Comment: String ascii="\u2588";
     
quoteText.setText(ascii); I did this and it is working perfectly fine no crash ??

Comment: Thank you @SALMAN That was too easy.  Much appreciated as this works without crashing my system or making me change file types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String ascii="\u2588"; 
quoteText.setText(ascii);
```

I did this way and it is working perfectly fine no crash.

Thanks :)